# AWS API Gateway returning different status via Postman to Method Test

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, http-status-codes, api-gateway

I have an AWS Lambda integrated into API Gateway. The lambda is current just returning an error:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.fail(JSON.stringify({
    status: 500,
    errors: 'This is definitely the same endpoint.'
  }));
};
```

I have added an HTTP status 500 response in method response of API Gateway, and I have mapped an integration response using regex *"status":500.* to the 500 response.

When I test this using the Method Test functionality in AWS, I get the 500 response I expect:

[image: AWS Method Test Response]

But when send command to the endpoint with Postman, I get a 200 status:

[image: Postman response]

How can this be? The Method Test seems to suggest my Integration Response and Method Response setups are correct, and I have my regex set up correctly, but what am I missing between the API Gateway and the rest of the world that would produce this different result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Deploying the API? Maybe a redeployment might fix the issues.

Comment: Yes, that was it.

Comment: This helped me as well after creating an API through CDK

Answer (score 0):

did you stumble across the [Handle Custom Lambda Errors in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html) guide already?

The format suggested there is:

```
{
   "isBase64Encoded" : "boolean",
   "statusCode": "number",
   "headers": { ... },
   "body": "JSON string"
}
```

So you basically need to return this JSON structure. I check this with [AWS serverless express library](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/blob/master/src/index.js) (line 100-105) - which we use - and it's returning this structure.

The major challenge is, that sending the HTTP response to the client is a task for the API Gateway and to do so, you must return a valid JSON response from the lambda in a format that the API gateway unterstands. The execution status of the lambda will be also 200 (because it worked A-Okay) but the API Gateway will transform your response into a 500. This is also why you nedd this double/triple JSON encoding (JSON-as-string in JSON-attributes).